# Do I have to drop tables once i change the django models

Tags: django

I am now to Django and i find that every time i change my models.py, i have to drop some tables to get things working again.Is there any better way?I really hate to drop tables.
Also,is it a problem that i find myself change models.py?what you would do if your site is up and running when you find you need to add something else to the models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have a look at [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)

Comment: South will give you more leisure time.